# CouchDB _changes message queue

Tags: service, queue, couchdb, task-queue

I want to have a service that listens to CouchDB database changes via `_changes` feed and i was wondering what will be the best way to pick a change that was missed maybe because, the DB  changes listener service was down.

I know this can be done by specifying `since=seq_no`, but i want something that can pull changes even if it happened while the listener service is down.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The [follow](https://github.com/iriscouch/follow) node js library does exactly this :)

Comment: I don't think follow does exactly what i want, i meant something that works as follows:   1.) Listen for changes and queue it up for processing, if there is any error, remember the last received changes from CouchDB and start from there. kinda a library that keeps track of the sequence numbers it received last or processed last.

Comment: Okay. But follow is the closest one to your requirements that I know. It can be a good starting point.

Comment: yes, am thinking of using something like Follow and a NodeJS message queue lib, to listen for changes, add changes to a queue and schedule a job, then keep track of last captured changes update_seq_number, then on restart pull changes since the last update_swq_number tracked.